# Nextjs conditional rendering of data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am trying to render data from an API, I have the data as a JSON if it loads plus I push an element if the fetch is successful

```
{status: 'success'}
```

If the fetch is not I push this

```
{status : 'failed}
```

When I try to render it on my main function like this

```
if(data.status === 'success'){
return <div> data </div>
} else if(data.status === 'failed'){
return <div> not data </div>
}
```

It gives me an error that I have nothing to return.

Comment: You must return something if all conditions fail. You could add a default else block  after your last if else. Add this
else{
return <div> default response</div>
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In React components, you need to return either a valid React element or `null`. You are not handling the condition when `data.status` is something other than `'success'` or `'failed'`, in which case you are not returning anything. You can do this by returning `null` at the end for the event that neither condition is met:

```
if(data.status === 'success'){
  return <div> data </div>
} else if(data.status === 'failed'){
  return <div> not data </div>
}
return null;
```

Answer (score 0):

when you send a http request maybe take a few seconds to catch response
But component rendering happens instantly

check this :

```
const ComponentName = () =>{
  return(
      <div>
          {data.status === 'success' && "data"}
          {data.status === 'failed' && "not data"}
      </div>
  );
};
```

If `status` doesn't have more than two modes you can write this :

```
const ComponentName = () =>{
  return(
      <div>
          {data.status === 'success' ? "data" : "not data"}
      </div>
  );
};
```